# how to set margin-top and left auto?

Tags: html, css

I have created a quotation box and i am showing 12 quotation boxes on a single page (3 per line,) but as quotations could be small or long, i want to keep margin fixed from top and left.

Live example is here>> http://fun2ush.com/quotations-by/abraham-lincon/, quotations are displaying here and there.

Below is the css i am using:

```
    .blockquote {
        width: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        background: #ffffff;
        font - family: Georgia,
        serif;
        font - size: 18px;
        font - style: italic;
        margin: 0.25em 0;
        padding: 0.25em 40px;
        line - height: 1.45;
        color: #100202;
        border-radius: 1px 47px 0px 47px;
        -moz-border-radius: 1px 47px 0px 47px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 1px 47px 0px 47px;
        border: 2px solid # 4f4f4f;
    }
    .blockquote p {
            color: #000000;
    }
    .blockquote:before {
        display: block;
        content: "\201C";
        font-size: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        left: -8px;
        top: -20px;
        color: # 00A0DA;
    } 
.wallpaper-box{float:left; margin:0px 15px 30px 15px; width:300px;}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="wallpaper-box"> 
    <div class="blockquote"> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </a>
            <div class="fb-like-box">
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink();?>" data-width="280" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">
                 </div> 
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve this in pure css, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/tQANc/

it makes use of

```
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 3%;
column-width: 30%;
```

in order to achieve this layout. This won't be supported on older browsers though (for older browsers you might want to fallback on masonry)

Implemented for your code (with an example of 3 columns):

```
.wallpaper-box{
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-width: 200px;
    min-width: 660px; /* add margins and paddings to calculate width */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your questions with CSS but this JS Library is amazing for doing what you are looking for.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Any reason for down votes? I am not the only person to suggest the Mansonry plugin and it is an awesome tool!

Answer (score 0):

Going by the look of the page of yours, my suggestion would be to use [**Masonry Plugin**](http://v3.desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) as its awesomely neat and does exactly what you want (i am assuming that the quotes are dynamic in terms of width and height)

Or default CSS way would be to use what suggested by `KristofFeys` or this  [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/hyhDg/1/)  (though his method is more clean under the assumption the column count is limited)

**HTML**

```
<div class="quote">
   <div class="one" style="border:1px solid #000">one</div>
   <div class="three" style="border:1px solid #000"> three three three</div>
<div class="five" style="border:1px solid #000">five five five five five   five five five five five   five five five five five   five five five five five   five five five five five   </div>
   <div class="seven" style="border:1px solid #000">seven seven seven seven seven seven seven </div>
</div>
<div class="quote">
   <div class="two" style="border:1px solid #000">two two</div>
   <div class="four" style="border:1px solid #000">four four four four </div>
   <div class="six" style="border:1px solid #000">six six six six six six </div>
   <div class="eight" style="border:1px solid #000">eight eight eight eight eight eight eight eight </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.quote {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```